# cut variable with symbol in label interval

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Rather than manually writing out interval labels would someone how to put a symbol e.g. `+` in the final interval of a variable that is `cut`?

I can cut a variable like so:

```
set.seed(1)
variab <- sample(0:100, 100, replace = FALSE)
variab
table(cut(variab, breaks = c(0, 1:4, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE))
#   [0,1]   (1,2]   (2,3]   (3,4] (4,Inf] 
#       2       1       0       1      96
```

If I want to put in a symbol I can do this:

```
table(cut(variab, breaks = c(0, 1:4, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE, labels = c(0:3, "4+")))
#  0  1  2  3 4+ 
#  2  1  0  1 96
```

But what i want is:

```
#   [0,1]   (1,2]   (2,3]   (3,4] (4, 4+] 
#       2       1       0       1      96
```

Separately, I would also like to do this deep within `dplyr` pipe:

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data.frame(variab)
df %>% 
  mutate(cut(variab, breaks = c(0, 1:4, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE))
```

I'm sure the answer is somewhere on SO but I cant track it down.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those `levels` are character values, you can change the levels using `sub`.

```
var <- cut(variab, breaks = c(0, 1:4, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE)
levels(var) <- sub('Inf', '4+', levels(var))
table(var)
#var
# [0,1]  (1,2]  (2,3]  (3,4] (4,4+] 
#     2      1      0      1     96
```

---

For the data in dataframe, you can do :

```
df %>% 
  mutate(var = cut(variab, breaks = c(0, 1:4, Inf), include.lowest=TRUE),
         var = sub('Inf', '4+', var))
```

Comment: You can use it in the same way in `dplyr` chain as well. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this too:

```
set.seed(1)
#Data
variab <- sample(0:100, 100, replace = FALSE)
#Vectors
breaks <- c(0, 1:4, Inf)
val <- max(breaks[is.finite(breaks)])
lev <- levels(cut(variab, breaks = breaks,
                  include.lowest=TRUE))
#Format
lev[length(lev)] <- gsub('Inf',paste0(val,'+'),lev[length(lev)])
#Table
table(cut(variab, breaks = breaks,
          include.lowest=TRUE,
          labels = lev))
```

Output:

```
 [0,1]  (1,2]  (2,3]  (3,4] (4,4+] 
     2      1      0      1     96
```